# ajax only working once

Tags: php, ajax

I am wanting to convert my website to ajax so I have been playing with it. I wrote a simple HTML page and PHP script but when I run it I keep getting the same time back. I am sure I am missing something simple but cant figure it out.

**PHP**

```
<?php
echo date("Y.m.d H:i:s", $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']);
?>
```

**HTML**

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<!-- 
//Browser Support Code
function ajaxFunction(){
var ajaxRequest;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!

try{
    // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
    ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
} catch (e){
    // Internet Explorer Browsers
    try{
        ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (e) {
        try{
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e){
            // Something went wrong
            alert("Your browser broke!");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
// Create a function that will receive data sent from the server
ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
        document.myForm.time.value = ajaxRequest.responseText;
    }
}
ajaxRequest.open("POST", "serverTime.php", true);
ajaxRequest.send(null); 
}
//-->
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name='myForm'>
Name: <input type='text'  name='username' /> <br />
Time: <input type='text' name='time' />
    <input type="button" onclick="ajaxFunction();" value="here">
</form> 
</body>
</html>
```

Every time I click the button I get the same time back. This makes me think that I am only talking to the server once. I want to be able to click the button every second and see the time change. Do I need some kind of code to reset my request each time?

Thanks in advance for any help. I need to understand this before I can move forward.

Comment: Consider using [JQuery](http://jquery.com) for the ajax stuff. Way easier to use and takes care of all browser related code.

Comment: Doing it yourself is always good for learning. But yeah I agree, too much to worry about in the long run.

Comment: I most likely will but I just wanted to see how it works. thanks for the help using time() works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'] which returns the time of the initial request. You need to use either time() or omit that parameter altogether.

Comment: REQUEST_TIME is the time of the start of the request. PHP is used stateless and has no notion of "initial request".

Comment: my first PHP was just date(H:i:s) and the same thing was happining. hold on i will try time().

Comment: time is working fine and is changeing every second. thanks i knew it was going to be something simple

Comment: I can't see how that would fix the problem O_o

Comment: @Adam because the request is a GET request and the response is being cached. Adding that parameter makes each request a new URL, which prevents the cached page from being pulled up. Does that help or am I missing what you're asking?

Comment: @Adam I was just in a rush. I meant start not initial.

Answer (score 2):

Responses may be cached by the browser. A simple hacky solution is to append a random get parameter to the url, e.g. `var url = "http://www.example.com/?rand=" + Math.random();`

Comment: This is how JQuery do it as well.

Answer (score 0):

move the ajaxRequest.open("POST", "serverTime.php", true); before ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function() line.

here is the ajax order

open()
onreadystatechange
send()